# SQL statement to linq lambda Orderby

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, lambda

I have this sql statement :

> SELECT QuestionNo, ActivityID, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Question, ' [',
>   Answer, ']') SEPARATOR ' ') AS joined from question GROUP BY
>   QuestionNo, ActivityID OrderBy questionHintID

I need to have it in linq lambda , so far what I have is

```
 IList<QuestionHint> lstRecords = context.questionhints.GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID, x.TaskID }).ToList().Select(g => new QuestionHint()
        {
            QuestionNo = g.Key.QuestionNo,
            ActivityID = g.Key.ActivityID,
            TaskID = g.Key.TaskID,
            joined = String.Join(" ",
                    g.Select(i => i.QuestionContent + "[" + i.Answer + "]")),
            joinOption = String.Join(" ",
                   g.Select(a => "[" + a.Option1 + "," + a.Option2 + "]"))

        }).Where(x => x.TaskID == listTask && x.ActivityID == listActivity)
            //.Take(50)
           .ToList();

        return lstRecords;
```

How do I add in the Orderby? because when i use join in the query , the records retrieve are out of order because the order is not guaranteed to be in order how do i add in OrderBy questionHintID ( primary key of the table ) to the above lambda?

Comment: You need to include `questionHintID` in your LINQ query, if it's not there you can't order on it.

Comment: err include it at where?

Comment: How does the ordering work in MySql? There can be any number of `questionHintID`s in each grouping. Does the ordering make sense at all?

Comment: questionHintID is the primary key , so theres a sequence like 1,2,3,4,5 ... so on and i need to order the records in sequence because when i use join query , the records are not guaranteed to be in order . For example , i have first record and second record in database , when i join them , it will appear secondrecordfirstrecord instead of firstrecordsecondrecord

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .OrderByDescending(questionhints => questionhint.ID)? Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean. It probably should be this: (note the `OrderBy` statements)

```
var lstRecords = context.questionhints
.Where(x => x.TaskID == listTask && x.ActivityID == listActivity)
.GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID, x.TaskID })
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(g => new QuestionHint()
        {
            QuestionNo = g.Key.QuestionNo,
            ActivityID = g.Key.ActivityID,
            TaskID = g.Key.TaskID,
            joined = String.Join(" ",
                       g.OrderBy(q => q.questionHintID)
                        .Select(i => i.QuestionContent + "[" + i.Answer + "]")),
            joinOption = String.Join(" ",
                       g.OrderBy(q => q.questionHintID)
                        .Select(a => "[" + a.Option1 + "," + a.Option2 + "]"))

        })
```